# Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined], not understanding how to proceed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To put you in situation, I have not clue how to use mongodb, mongoose and all the other tools shown below.
I used a tutorial to implement this code long ago, and now I see myself on the need of expanding the project I'm working in. So now I'm trying to scratch here and there in order to form the code needed.

The case is that I'm duplicating the needed files in order to create another model/collection. I had all the files related to "user", and now I'm willing to CRUD "repair_dispatches"*(shown as "partes_reparacion below)*.

So, In the main file, called server.js:

```
    'use strict'
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bodyParserJSON = bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb',extended:true});
const bodyParserURLEncoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true, limit: '50mb'});
const configMensaje = require('./configMensaje');
const authRoutes = require('./auth/auth.routes');
const router = express.Router();
const properties = require('./auth/config/properties');
const DB = require('./auth/config/db');
const expressjwt = require('express-jwt');
const reparacionesRoutes = require('./reparaciones/reparaciones.routes');

DB();
app.use(bodyParserJSON);
app.use(bodyParserURLEncoded);
app.use(cors({origin: "*"}))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  next();
});

app.use('/api',router);
authRoutes(router);
reparacionesRoutes(router); <<--this is the line that when inserted, gives the error.

router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello from home');
});

app.use(router);

app.listen(properties.PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${properties.PORT}`));
```

And I just copied the files from my auth folder which includes: auth.controller.js, auth.dao.js, auth.model.js, and auth.routers.js, created another folder for the repairing model, and changed everything related, leaving the structure the same:

**reparaciones.controller.js**

```
const parte = require('./reparaciones.dao');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

exports.guardarParte = (req,res,next) =>{
    /* console.log("request:xxxxxxxxxx "+JSON.stringify(req.body)); */
    const newParte = {
        id: req.body.id,
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        telefono:  req.body.telefono,
        ref: req.body.ref,
        marca: req.body.marca,
        fecha: req.body.fecha,
        averia: req.body.averia 
    }
    console.log(req.body);
    parte.update({'id':newParte.id},newParte, (err,res)=>{
        if(err && err.code === 11000){
            return res.status(409).send("El parte ya existe(?)");
        }
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send("No se ha podido crear el parte");
        }
            //response
            res.send(newParte)
    })

}
```

**reparaciones.dao.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authSchema = require('./reparaciones.model');

authSchema.statics = {
    guardar: function (data,cb){
        const parte = new this(data);
        parte.guardar(cb);
    },
    borrar: function (data,cb){
        const parte = new this(data);
        parte.delete(cb);
    },
    buscaruno: function(query,cb){
        this.find(query,cb);
    },
    cargartodos: function(query,cb){
        this.find(query,cb);
    }
}

const authModel = mongoose.model('partes_reparacion',authSchema);
module.exports = authModel;
```

**reparaciones.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex',true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology',true);

const reparacionSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    telefono: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        trim: true
    },
    ref: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true
    },
    marca: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true
    },
    fecha: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true
    },
    averia: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true
    },
},{
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = reparacionSchema;
```

**reparaciones.routes.js**

```
const Parte = require('./reparaciones.controller');
module.exports = (router)=>{
    router.post('/guardarParte', Parte.guardarParte);
    router.post('/buscaruno', Parte.buscarUnParte);
    router.post('/cargartodos', Parte.cargarTodosPartes);
}
```

So, these 4 files are just a modification of the auth files, which were working correctly. But when adding the line in the server.js "reparacionesRoutes(router);" as shown in the first code snippet, i get the mentioned error. I don't know why just by including another instance it gives the error.

Also, after starting the server with npm start, it goes to mongodb://localhost:27017/users. Shouldn't it start on root so I go to the desired route depending on the post url?

Comment: A lot of stuff, okay, but where is the error stack?

Comment: Sorry, thought the title would be enough. 
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (C:\~Desarrollo\Tests\nodetest\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Function.proto.<computed> [as post] (C:\~Desarrollo\Tests\nodetest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
    at module.exports (C:\~Desarrollo\Tests\nodetest\reparaciones\reparaciones.routes.js:4:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\~Desarrollo\Tests\nodetest\server.js:30:1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be not the answer you are looking for. Just mentioning some things I have noticed.

In below code you are importing `./reparaciones.controller` as `Parte`.
But you have only exported `guardarParte` from controller like so :- `exports.guardarParte = (req,res,next) =>{`.

I don't see `exports.buscarUnParte` and `exports.cargarTodosPartes` in the file you have shared.(I am assuming you have shared complete file).

Hence `Parte.buscarUnParte` and `Parte.cargarTodosPartes` evaluates to undefined.

```
const Parte = require('./reparaciones.controller');
module.exports = (router)=>{
    router.post('/guardarParte', Parte.guardarParte);
    router.post('/buscaruno', Parte.buscarUnParte); //2nd parameter is undefined
    router.post('/cargartodos', Parte.cargarTodosPartes); //2nd parameter is undefined
}
```

Hope this will point you in right direction.